# How to add a new option to vuetify v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am loading data to a v-select with and api.  I am trying to add a new option, with value 0 and name all. I have tried the following code but it does not look right.   Is there any other way that I could accomplish this.

```
            <v-select
              :items="familias"
              v-model="familiaFiltroId"
              label="Familia"
              item-text="nombre"
              item-value="familiaId"
              dense
              outlined
              required
            >
              <template v-slot:append-item>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
                <v-list-tile >
                  <v-list-tile-content>
                    <option value="0">-- All--</option>
                  </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>
              </template>
            </v-select>
```

Comment: Try not to manipulate the html directly, go for the data behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the new element to the beginning of `familias` after populating it:

```js
let familias = [{"nombre":"1","familiaId":"1"},{"nombre":"2","familiaId":"2"}];
familias.unshift({"nombre":"--All--","familiaId":"0"});
console.log(familias);
```